# Pop to view controller not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Hi everyone in an IBAction I have

```
ProfileViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileViewController"];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"tapped");
```

And then when I click the button, I see the "tapped" is logged but the view controller doesn't go?

Why does it not pop to the new view controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`popToViewController` goes backwards to a `ViewController` already on the navigation stack.

You need to use `pushViewController`

Comment: I have already been on the view controller I am trying to pop too. I am pushed to the current and want to go back 2 view controllers, but it is not the root.

Comment: In that case you need a reference to the ViewController you want to pop to. In your code, you are instantiating a new instance of your VC.

You can get the ViewController through the UINavigationController's viewControllers property

Comment: Okay, can you show me what you mean about getting the VC thought the UINavigations viewController property?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers